# Self Hosted WCF Service throws Error Message "405 Method not allowed"

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a Self Hosted WCF Service, which looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]    
public interface IService {
    [OperationContract]     
    [WebGet]   
    List<Data> GetData();
    //...and much more Methods
}
```

My App.config looks like this:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MetaInformation">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"
                         httpGetUrl="http://localhost:8500/MetaInfo"
                         httpsGetBinding="" />
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="EndpointBehavior">
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>     
    <service behaviorConfiguration="MetaInformation" name="Library.WcfService.ServiceModel">
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8500/Service"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBindingSettings"
                contract="Library.WcfService.IService"
                bindingName="BasicHttpBindingSettings"
               behaviorConfiguration="EndpointBehavior"/>                        
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>      
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBindingSettings"
               closeTimeout="00:50:00"
               openTimeout="00:50:00"
               sendTimeout="00:50:00"
               maxBufferSize="524288"
               transferMode="Streamed"
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
               maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
               messageEncoding="Text">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                      maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                      maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>

<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400"/>    
</system.web>
```

When I run this Server and the Client Applications on my local machine, it's working fine. 
But when i try to run the Server Application on another PC, I cannot add a Service Reference at the Client because I get this:

> 405 Method not allowed Metadata contains a reference that can not be resolved : "http://192.168.178.54:8500/MetaInfo". It was not a
>   listening to http://192.168.178.54:8500/MetaInfo endpoint present who
>   could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect
>   address or SOAP action

I tried almost everything I found at the internet but nothing worked. 
Switching to IIS or using an other Protocol should be a plan B, i want to keep it self hosted with http.

Please can somebody help me I'm desperate with this Problem.

Comment: Could you tell us which .NET Version is installed on the other Computer and if you copied all required dll's (from usings in each class) not profided by .NET to the other computer's WCF-bin Folder? It may be that ether .NET is not installed (in the required min-Version) or you have something in your GAC (global assembly Cache) the other Computer doesn't have.

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.0 on Both machines. I just copied the whole VS Solution to the Other PC for Debugging.
When I run the Client on the other PC it works too. I get this error only if I try to use the WCF Service over the LAN.

Answer (score 0):

your operation contract is decorated with `[WebGet]` attribute, which means you're trying to expose your service as a `REST`. But your service is using `basicHttpBinding` as means of building the communication channel which isn't supported because the content type for this binding is `soap+xml`. You'll need to use `WebHttpBinding` in this case which is the only binding that supports restful implementation of `WCF Services` and supports both `Xml` and `Json` data types.

Comment: I changed my App.config to WebHttpBinding. Still getting the 405 error :(

Comment: Yes, its in my answer.

Comment: Finally I found the error! Instead of using "localhost" or "0.0.0.0" I have to define the exact IP. In this case 192.168.178.54. Then it works.